# AnkiDroid on Kindle Fire (Addons)?

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, ankidroid

How can I add addons to my Kindle Fire 7 HD version of AnkiDroid downloaded from GoogleCode (featured)?

Answer (score 1):

AnkiDroid developer here.

Google Code is not used anymore, it only contains very old versions that are not compatible with anything anymore.

The newest versions can be found here:

https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/releases

That being said, Addons are not available yet for AnkiDroid.
We have started developing an Addon system but it won't be ready before next year, thanks for your comprehension!

Comment: That's cool.  I'm just trying to get Japanese and Chinese TTS (text-to-speech) support.  If I can't get an engine with a Japanese and Chinese voice, is it impossible for me to get Japanese and Chinese TTS on AnkiDroid?  Or could I somehow use AnkiDesktop to bulk-add TTS as media?

Comment: Okay, I found a way: install the AwesomeTTS add-on for Anki Desktop.  Go to the browser.  Select the deck you want readings for.  Hit ctrl-a to select all of the cards.  Click "AwesomeTTS" from the drop-down menu.  Click "Add Readings to Cards".  Then, you can sync and fetch media.